# Can one exonerate oneself?

Tags: word-choice

You can exonerate, and be exonerated - but the word seems to be used in reference to an other.  Is it proper to use the word when applying to the self?

So, can one literally exonerate oneself?  Of course if the word is intended it conveys the meaning without hiccup - but has this word been used as intended?

(and is *exo-* a prefix in this instance?)

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly fine to say that. 'exo' is not a prefix here (or rather  the rest of the word doesn't produce other words with other affixes).

Comment: @Mitch If you look at Hans Adler's excellent answer below, you will see that *ex* is certainly a prefix - from the Latin *ex-onerare*.

Comment: @WS2 Sure, 'ex-' is a very productive prefix in English. My point was that '-oner' is not, which, to answer the OPs parenthetical question, means that 'exo' is not a prefix in this instance.

Comment: @Mitch But the Latin verb *onerare* - to charge or to burden - works independently of the prefix *ex* in such English words as the *onus* (of proof).

Comment: @WS2 ...or 'onerous' or ... well that's it, and those aren't productive and 'exo-' is still not a prefix. The OP is asking 'is "exo-" a prefix?'. The answer is 'no, it is not'. Can you use 'exo-' to add to the front of other roots to make new words? No, you cannot. There's a difference between 'ex-' and 'exo-', and the OP asked about and I answered about the latter. I'm not sure what you're trying to respond to, but it's not anything I or the OP have written about.

Comment: @Mitch I too am unsure how we got on to the topic, but if someone writes something that is clearly incorrect I am likely to respond. Of course *exo..* can be used as a prefix to other words. What about *exocentric*, *exothermic*, etc. Take a look at [this list](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_prefixed_with_exo-)

Comment: @WS2 Yes, you are right that 'exo-' is a prefix in general, and often. My error in my previous comment, I'll give you that. But the OP asked, and I first commented, whether 'exo-' was a prefix here, and I answered it is not. It parses out here as 'ex-' and '-onerate', not 'exo-' and '-nerate'.

Comment: @Mitch I'm glad that we have ended in agreement. Mutual misunderstanding seemed to dominate that little exchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In its primary sense, to exonerate someone means to prove their innocence. If you prove your own innocence, you exonerate yourself.

However, the verb is sometimes used as the antonym of *convict*: Someone accused of a crime is either convicted or exonerated. Of course a person cannot exonerate themselves in this sense any more than they can convict themselves, for lack of authority.

As to the etymology, the Latin verb *onerare* means to charge or to burden. Naturally, *ex-onerare* means to remove a charge or burden.